# How can I allow to enlarge and shrink of a window only certain steps?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-interface

I have a Windows Form with floating layout. In this layout, there are several elements of the same size. The form can be free scaled at the moment. My problem now is that this can rise to a large open space on the right edge.

I now want to ensure that the user can drag the window size only in certain steps. The solution should work on both axles.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider using `Dock`, `Anchor`, `FlowLayoutPanel`, `TableLayoutPanel`, `MaximumSize`, ...

Comment: What are the "steps" you are referring here? The answers can be narrow or broad, easy or difficult, depending on the "steps" you are referring to.

Comment: I mean that the window width modulo five must be always zero.
The same applies to the window height.